# .htaccess - Page Redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

Basically what I need is to make the server ignore the url when it have the string index.php?route=index and in this case, instead redirecting it to www.mysite.com.br/index.htm as its currently doing it have to redirect it to index.php?route=index itself.

see my .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^/index.php?route=index$[L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.mysite.com.br/index.php?route=index [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-_/]+)?$ ./index.htm [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-_/]+)/?$ ./index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-_/]+)?$ ./index.php?route=index [L,QSA]
```

Comment: why not use a session cookie to 'remember' the user has clicked. Then redirect depending on existence of the cookie.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a `cookie` with the button result of the warning message. The first time, if `cookie` doesn't exist, show your warning. If exists, jump the warning part.

Set the `cookie` duration to session (close browser).